# Is there a way to repeat an if statement in VBA for excel depending on what cell you are on

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on building a excel workbook that I want to be able to hide cells based on a data validation. The code I have already works fine.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C2"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "A": Rows("18:41").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                                          Rows("6:17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "B": Rows("6:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                                          Rows("30:41").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case Is = "C": Rows("6:41").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that this could be repeated up to possibility of 8 times (being done with a similar data validation). But each time the target address would change and the rows that need to be hidden would change. IE Round 2 target address cell would be "C42" and the rows that would need to be hidden would be changing their hidden or not would be rows 46:81.

My initial plan is just to create 8 individual If statements each dedicated to the group in question. I was seeing if there was a cleaner way to repeat this same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by storing the values A, B, C and so on,  in an array. You should also store the corresponding range addresses in an array. Then it's just a matter of looping to figure out which letter got matched.

The code would look like:

```
for i = 1 to letters.length
    if target.value = letters(i) then
        Rows(addresses(i)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Exit for
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.

Comment: You are welcome :-). Please have a look at named cells. It will simplify your life. Another thing: from a long experience building solutions with Excel, as the solution grows, you have to stay more and more disciplined and avoid hardcoding addresses or if anything ends up hardcoded, create constants with descriptive names with the hardcoded addresses, values or whatever. Failing to do that, your code will soon turn into a maintenance nightmare. I also advise you to have a look at what Python can do and possibly transition to that. It cuts on code and greatly simplifies lengthy VBA coding.

Comment: Yeah I hope to move to python or something else in the future this is a paperwork generator. But I will need to build a GUI for the end users, which is still something I'm learning how to do. I will need to build a complex GUI (Excel sheet currently has 15 sheets in the workbook and will probably expand). What it's doing isn't very complex math wise its just moving information around with the correct parameters.